# In bash, can I pass an array as args of a function (as xargs does)?

Tags: bash, git-bash

I am using a bash script to generate a list of files, where each file name might contain spaces (it is on Windows, with Git Bash, and I need something that works with Bash 3).

The script does roughly that:

```
_my_function() {
  for i; do 
    echo $i
  done
}

_test() {
  local do_add_list
  do_add_list[0]='Some file'
  do_add_list[1]='Another file'  
  _my_function $do_add_list[@]
}
```

While I don’t really want to pass the array as is, I’d like to pass it as arguments of `_my_function` like `xargs` or as something like,

```
_my_function 'Some file' 'Another file'
```

How can I do that in **Bash 3** (msys port of bash3), apart from as a global variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of

```
_my_function $do_add_list[@]
```

do

```
_my_function "${do_add_list[@]}"
```

Comment: It worked. I don't know how bash does it, but _my_function `a ${do_add_list[@]} b` also prepend to first array args, and append to last array args. I just hope it will not fails on Windows (I tested it on ubuntu).